# Does x particular lie in column space of A?

Tags: linear-algebra

The solution for  $  A \mathbf  x = \mathbf b $ relationship depends on the solutions from Nullspace of $ A $($ x_{{nullspace}} $) and the particular solution ($ x_{{particular}} $). 
$$ x =  x_{{nullspace}} + x_{{particular}} $$

Does  $ x_{{particular}} $ lie in the Column Space of A ($ col(A)$)?

Comment: It's $\bf b$ that belongs to the column space of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

No. For example, we have

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2\\ 3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}5\\ 5\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$\begin{pmatrix}2\\ 3\end{pmatrix}$$ does not belong to $\rm{col}(A).$